# Angular property updates on DOM, but not in class method

Tags: angular

EDIT: The date-picker opens a modal, so when I click the button, the first thing to be clicked is the modal's overlay, and then the button. This means that when a user clicks the button, what is actually happening is that the overlay is being clicked (which closes the modal) and then the button's (click) event is fired (opening the modal again). So the user just sees no change.

I have a property in my parent component's class: `calendarOpen: boolean;`. When I open and close a calendar component ([`ng2-date-picker`](https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker)), the `calendarOpen` property is updated:
**parent.component.html**

```html
<dp-date-picker
  #dateComponent
  (close)="closed()"
  (open)="opened()"
...
<button (click)="buttonClicked(calendarOpen)">click me</button>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
  opened(): void {
    this.calendarOpen = true;
  }

  closed(): void {
    this.calendarOpen = false;
  }
```

This works, insofar as I can see the `calendarOpen` value change if I add it to the DOM:

```html
<span>calendarOpen:{{calendarOpen}}</span>
```

But if I try to use the `calendarOpen` value in a method in my class, the value never updates to `true`:
**parent.component.ts**

```
buttonClicked() {
    const {calendarOpen} = this;
    console.log({
      calendarOpen
    });
// This initially logs 'undefined' and then subsequently 'false', 'false', 'false', etc..
}
```

Why is my class/typescript not picking up a change when my html is? How do I get the class method to keep up to date with the property value?

Comment: The buttonClicked method is defined in `parent.component.ts` and fired from a button's `(click)` event. I've updated the post above. How/where would I use `this.buttonClicked`?

Comment: There is a typo error in my previous comment. Apologizes for that. Perhaps using `this.calendarOpen` instead of creating a destructuring assignment (`const {calendarOpen} = this;`)?

Comment: Is the picker is closed on outside click? If yes, when clicking the "click me" button, this would be an outside click and the `close` event is fired, which would explain this behavior.